# Android: How to propagate ActivityResult before starting a new Intent (e.g. open browser or deeplink)?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

There are two activities in my project. The `MainActivity` starts the `SecondActivity` with the following code:

```kotlin
private val secondActivityLauncher = registerForActivityResult(SecondActivity.Contract()) {
        when (it) {
            is SecondActivity.SecondActivityOutput.Success -> {
                // TODO
            }
            // ...
        }
    }
```

If a certain condition has been met, `SecondActivity` sets the result with code:

```kotlin
setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, Intent().putExtra("MY_DATA_EXTRA", "some data"))
```

If the condition was not met, `SecondActivity` returns `Activity.RESULT_CANCELED` code.

This works fine in all cases except one: when the SecondActivity has to start a new Intent (e.g. open browser or deeplink) and at the same time finish itself and propagate the `Activity.RESULT_OK` result to `MainActivity`.

I tried this:

```kotlin
setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, Intent().putExtra("MY_DATA_EXTRA", "some data"))
finish()
startActivity(Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://www.google.com")))
```

But it doesn't work that way. The `Activity.RESULT_OK` value is only passed to `MainActivity` when the user closes the web browser activity.

Is it possible to implement this in such a way that `SecondActivity` will first return a result to `MainActivity`, and only then the browser will be started?

Comment: Perhaps these should not be separate activities, but rather a single activity with multiple fragments or composables for the screens.

Comment: Yes, I agree. But unfortunately, this part of the application is already structured in the way described, and refactoring it would be complicated/time-consuming... So I'm first trying to find a solution without having to modify the `MainActivity`

Comment: Hmm, maybe try `Intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)` ? As long as MainActivity doesn't close, that flag should finish the activity and send the result. I am not completely sure though.

Comment: Another alternative would be finishing the `SecondActivity`, receiving a different result in `MainActivity` and open the `ThirdActivity` from there if it needs to be opened, and merging the `onActivityResult` code in `SecondActivity` into `MainActivity`.

Answer (score 2):

You could move the browser opening in the `MainActivity` once the result is received:

```
private val secondActivityLauncher = registerForActivityResult(SecondActivity.Contract()) {
    when (it) {
        is SecondActivity.SecondActivityOutput.Success -> {
            if (it.resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                // Get the result data
                const data = it.data?.getStringExtra("MY_DATA_EXTRA")

                // Open the browser
                startActivity(Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://www.google.com")))
            }
        }
        // ...
    }
}
```